# Не работает rgb функция

Tags: javascript

Нужна ваша помощь. Я пытаюсь создать с помощью JavaScript color pallete. Типа, при движении мышкой по блоку, изменялся цвет. Дело в том, что ошибок мне не указывает, координаты мне указывает, где я навел мышкой, но блок цветом не заполняется. Что я делаю не так?

```
<div id="rgb"></div>

<script>
let box = document.getElementById('rgb')

box.onmousemove = function (e) {
   console.log(e.x, e.y)
   this.style.background = `rgb(${e.x}, ${e.y}, ${e.z})`
}
</script>
```

Comment: Просто сделайте ``console.log(`rgb(${e.x}, ${e.y}, ${e.z})`)`` чтобы посмотреть, что конкретно вы пихаете в стили, и увидеть ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так?

```js
let box = document.getElementById('rgb')

box.onmousemove = function (e) {
   e.z = e.x + e.y;
   console.log(e.x, e.y, e.z);
   this.style.background = `rgb(${e.x}, ${e.y}, ${e.z})`
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="rgb"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо работает). `e.z = e.x + e.y;` - что это значит? Оно после добавления этой строчки начало работать?

Comment: у тебя e.z было undefined, то есть её неоткуда брать

Comment: Год назад у меня работало так, не знаю почему сейчас так. Спасибо вам

Comment: Прошу прощение, но если этот ответ был правильным можно галочку поставить?)